# XSL Rendering of Line feed &#10; is different between IE8 and IE9

Tags: xml, google-chrome, xslt, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am rendering XML Dom object and facing a very serious issue. An issue is:
I want to break the line whenever I get `"&#10;"` and `"&#172;"`.

In IE8 : It renders properly `"&#10;"` (New Line) and put `<br>` tag where it has found `"&#10;"`. But in IE9 it breaks each and every word into new lines wherever it found `"&#10;"` and a white space (single space)

```
<xsl:template name="for-each-character">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="lf"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="sr"><xsl:text>&#172;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($data) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($data,1,1)"/>
        <xsl:if test="substring($data,1,1) = $sr or substring($data,1,1) = $lf">
            <br/>
        </xsl:if>
            <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

***Output in IE8:***

Hello this is a Text going on new line¬
after spec character

***Output in IE9:***

Hello 
 this 
 is 
 .... and so for

***Expected output should be (both in IE8 and IE9 (or >=IE9):***

Hello this is a Text going on new line¬
after spec character

Above template is properly working in Chrome and IE8 but creates problem in IE9.

Will appreciate any further assistance.

Comment: Where are the new lines in the actual source data? You say "in IE9 it breaks each and every word into new lines wherever it found `&#10;` and a white space (single space)" Are you saying that there is a new line between every word in your source data? Because the XSLT you have there will add `<br/>`s wherever there is a `&#10;`.

Comment: No. Actually data will be in a simple text format. Let say: This is a sample Text (new line) This is a new line. Where new line will be containing standard \r\n combination.

Comment: @JLRishe: Text will be stored from Textarea (as usual) and may contain pair of \r\n if enter key is pressed (paragraph). Now when I render it from XSL then `&#10;` is not properly recognized by IE9 and it splits each word of line in new lines (likewise I said "breaks down each word of sentence"). 
Means it splits each word of sentence irrelevant of `&#10;` or ''

May I have explained it?

Comment: Now this question has been resolved by taking an example from this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840040/detecting-incoming-xml-cr-character-then-converting-to-br/15924781#15924781)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to use `&#xA;` instead of `&#10;` when dealing with IE (at least IE9 and below).

Comment: Solution I found is that I have to use &#xA; instead of &#10; for IEs